# How to pass typename T in class A to use in another class B

Tags: c++, templates

I have an issue with templates. How could I pass `typename T` into `class A` to use it in `class B`? I would like to pass typename only in `class A` but I also need to use it in `class B`. Is it possible at all?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    B getObj() { return obj; };
    void setObj(B bObj) { obj = bObj; };
private:
    B obj;
};

template <typename T>
class B {
public:
    T getValue() { return value; };
    void setValue(T val) { value = val; };
private:
    T value = 0;
};

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    a.setObj(B()); // Is it possible to write B without typename every time?

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles with such errors:

```
error C3646: 'getObj': unknown override specifier
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'A<T>' being compiled
error C2059: syntax error: '('
error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'B'
error C3646: 'obj': unknown override specifier
error C2059: syntax error: '='
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

---

**Edit.**

Simplified code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class B {
public:
    T value;
};

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    B obj;
};

int main() {
    B<int> b;            // can I simply write B b intead of B<int> b?
    b.value = 9;

    A<int> a;
    a.obj = b;

    cout << a.obj.value; // ?

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles with errors:

```
error C2955: 'B': use of class template requires template argument list
note: see declaration of 'B'
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'A<T>' being compiled
error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'B'
warning C4552: '<<': result of expression not used
```

Comment: I would suggest you to get your code correct without template first. `B obj = NULL;` suggests that you are not aware of c++ having value semantics....

Comment: There are no classes `A` and `B`– they are class templates. `A<int>` is a class; `B` isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to write it even without `B`:

```
template<typename T>
struct B {};

template<typename T>
struct A {
    void setObj(B<T> obj) {
        obj_ = obj;    // or obj_ = std::move(obj);
    }

    B<T> obj_;
};

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    a.setObj({});
}
```

This will work unless the constructors of `B` are marked as `explicit`.

---

To refer to `B<T>` inside `A<T>`, you can introduce a type alias:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    using B = ::B<T>;

    void setObj(B obj) {
        obj_ = obj;
    }

    B obj_;
};

int main() {
    using my_A = A<int>;
    my_A a;
    a.setObj(my_A::B{});
}
```

---

**Addition after edit.**

You can't omit a template argument, unless a compiler can somehow deduce it. In C++17 we have [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction), and your code can be written as:

```
template<typename T>
struct B {
    B(T v) : value(v) {}
    T value;
};

template<typename T>
struct A {
    A(B<T> o) : obj(o) {}
    B<T> obj;
};

int main() {
    B b{9};
    A a{b};

    std::cout << a.obj.value;
}
```

Comment: Ok. Your code is good, but can you explain me on my example? *upd question*

Comment: @entithat, please do not rewrite your question. After edit it should be `B<T> obj;`. You can't omit this `<T>`.

Comment: I just simplified my code. Question is still the same. It's all is a little bit confusing for me.

Comment: @entithat, these is no magic is template argument specification. A compiler will not make guesses. Either you provide it explicitly, or it can be deduced from types of constructor parameters (since C++17 only).